# Splitting multipart polygons to single part in R?

Tags: r, multipart, singlepart

I am looking for the equivalent of "Convert multipart features to multiple singlepart features. Creates simple polygons and lines" in QGIS and similar in ArcGIS for R. Various analyses create multipart features (in class `sf`, they are in the class `MULTIPOLYGON` or `MULTILINESTRING`) when the desired output is a simple polygons or simple lines (in class `sf`, they are in the class `POLYGON` or `LINESTRING`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using the `sf` classes then you cast it from MULTIPOLYGON to POLYGON. Example using data from `spData` package:

```
ncsf = st_read(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package = "spData")[1])
> dim(ncsf)
[1] 100  23
```

100 features there. Some are MULTIPOLYGON, so let's split:

```
> ncmp = st_cast(ncsf,"POLYGON")
Warning message:
In st_cast.sf(ncsf, "POLYGON") :
  repeating attributes for all sub-geometries for which they may not be constant
```

And now we have:

```
> dim(ncmp)
[1] 108  23
```

more features.

The warning is just to note that if you split features then things like "population" might not be appropriate to copy across split features (but "population density" might be...)

If you are using `sp` classes I would say "use `sf` classes", and if you can't use `sf` classes for your work I would say "convert to `sf`, then split, then convert back to `sp` classes".

```
#convert sf to sp for use with other functions
ncsf_sp<-as(ncsf, "Spatial")
#convert sp to sf for use with this function 
ncsf_sp<-as(ncsf_sp, "sf")
```

Comment: To add to this, I've discovered the hard way that `lwgeom::st_make_valid()` followed by `st_cast()` all to MULTIPOLYGON and then finally `st_cast()` all to POLYGON can be the only safe method of preserving all geometries in some cases - especially when converting data that's come out of ESRI File Geodatabases.

Comment: If your analyses somehow turned your polygons into class `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` (you'll find this out because you get an error message), it may be necessary to first cast to `MULTIPOLYGON` before casting to `POLYGON`. This can be done in one line: `st_cast(ncsf, "MULTIPOLYGON" ) %>% st_cast("POLYGON")`

Comment: I want to split only one polygon into its constituents while leaving the other multipolygon features as is. Is that achievable using `sf::st_cast()` ??

Answer (score 1):

When using the `sp class`, there are two functions that explode multipart features into single part features.

1. `ms_explode` from `rmapshaper` which works for multipart polygons and multipart lines but not for SpatialMultiPoints as described in the help file for [feature](http://127.0.0.1:14163/library/rmapshaper/html/ms_explode.html).
2. `disaggregate` from `sp` also splits into single parts but I have found situations where it leads to an error (stating an rgeos error with sp feature) when the same feature converted to `sf` could be split using `st_cast`. While I don't understand the behaviour, I have noticed that it can be unstable.